# Issue with pausing audio in Howler and react

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

Please have a look at this simple code -

```
  const PlayPause = () => {
    const sound = new Howl({
      src: [
        "https://..." // I have a link to an mp3 file stored in an S3 bucket
      ],
      loop: true,
      volume: 0.5
    })

    const [ isPlaying, setIsPlaying ] = useState(false)

    const togglePlay = () => {
          if (isPlaying) {
              sound.pause()
              setIsPlaying(false)
          } else {
              sound.play()
              setIsPlaying(true)
          }
    }

    return (
      <button onClick={ togglePlay }>Press me</button>
    )
  }

  export default PlayPause
```

I'm trying to create a simple play/pause toggle for a Howler audio file streaming from the web. All my react functions are working fine. When I click on the div, `play` works correctly but `pause` doesn't. In fact, it actually plays multiple instances of the audio file whenever I click on play. Is there something wrong I'm doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared 'sound' inside the const PlayPause. For sound.pause() to work the access of 'sound' should be global.
Do it like this:

```
let sound = new Howl({
  src: [
    "https://...", // I have a link of an mp3 file stored in an S3 bucket
  ],
  loop: false,
  volume: 0.5,
});

const PlayPause = () => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button
      className="volume main-box dummy-abs"
      onClick={() => {
        // Toggles play / pause

        if (isPlaying) {
          sound.pause();
          setIsPlaying(false);
        } else {
          sound.play();
          setIsPlaying(true);
        }
        console.log("isPlaying", isPlaying);
      }}
    >
      Press Me
    </button>
  );
};

export default PlayPause;
```

Hopefully it will work.

You can use react-howler if you are not comfortable with global access. With react-howler you can do it like this:

```
import ReactHowler from "react-howler";

const PlayPause = () => {
  const [playpause, setPlaypause] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactHowler
        src="https://..."
        playing={playpause}
        //ref={(ref) => (this.player = ref)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setPlaypause(!playpause)}> Press Me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlayPause;
```

Comment: Yes, it works when I make the Howl available globally. Thank you.

Comment: What if I have to pass props inside Howler({}) ??

Comment: use react-howler library

Comment: "let" is not allowed for global